# Testing misuse exceptions in mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I wanted to test a misuse exception in mockito just for educational purposes to demonstrate the error:

```
    @Test
    public void testNotAMockException() {
        try {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            Mockito.doReturn(100).when(list).size();

            fail("Should have thrown a NotAMockException because list is not a mock!");
        } catch (NotAMockException e) {
            assertThat(e.getMessage(), containsString("Argument passed to when() is not a mock!"));
        }

    }
```

This behaves correctly and the assertion passes, but then the test fails with a `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException`

I understand why but is there a way I can suppress the TestFailue being fired by Mockito at the end?

Thanks

Comment: I ve run this same test using junit:4.12, mockito-all:1.10.19, hamcrest-all:1.3, but the test passes.

Comment: I have mockito core 2.21

Comment: Test passes here too with mockito-core:2.23.0 junit: 4.12 and hamcrest-cire 1.3

Comment: I think the problem is using: @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) - if I remove this, it does work actually.

Comment: It does say this in the docs - Both built-in runner: MockitoJUnitRunner and rule: MockitoRule do validateMockitoUsage() after each test method.